# Value Error in reading tif image with pil in python?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

I have to read a tif image of size *2200x 2200* and type uint16. I use PIL library with anaconda python as follows:

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('test.tif')
img.imshow()
```

I got following error with this: `ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image`

What could be the reason for this and how to fix this? I am using anaconda python3.6.1 version

Comment: same with `Image.open()`?

Comment: sorry sir actually I used ' Image.open()'

Comment: Can you also try `img = Image.open('test.tiff')`

Comment: I have tried sir and got `File not found Error`...

Comment: try with this : Image.open(open('test.tif', 'rb'))

Comment: I got same error `ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image`

Comment: @vishnusaini can you check in the properties of the image, what type it is?

Comment: It's a TIF file and SAR(Synthetic Aperture Radar ) image. Still i did't find any way to fix this error in PIL library. So i am using opencv library to read the image as- `cv2.imread("test.tif", -1)` .

Answer (score 0):

This is because there is an error in the image encoding; the tiles in the TIF file actually do extend outside the image. You can confirm this by viewing the tiles:

`img.tile`

which will output something like:

`[('tiff_lzw', (0, 0, 240, 240), 16, 'RGB'),
 ('tiff_lzw', (240, 0, 480, 240), 94905, 'RGB'),
...
 ('tiff_lzw', (720, 960, 960, 1200), 1711985, 'RGB'),
 ('tiff_lzw', (960, 960, 1200, 1200), 1730566, 'RGB')]`

In the case of my example above, the image dimensions were `1000x1000` pixels, but clearly the tiles extend to `1200x1200`. You can either crop the image to the expected size (losing some information), or expand the image size to include all the tiles. See examples here:

https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/3044

i.e., `im.size = (1000, 1000)` or `im.tile = [e for e in im.tile if e[1][2] < 1200 and e[1][3] < 1200]`