# matplotlib PIL reading tif - ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-imaging-library, tiff

I would like to read a [tif file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBFcN.png) with basically the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
filename = 'test.tif'
plt.imread(filename)
```

This results in the following error message (just the last lines):

```
File ".../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 692, in tobytes
self.load()
File ".../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1013, in load
return super(TiffImageFile, self).load()
File ".../miniconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line 204, in load
decoder.setimage(self.im, extents)
ValueError: tile cannot extend outside image
```

When I open the tif image with imagemagick's display and save it without making changes, everything works normally.
Nevertheless, I think it could a problem with my python environment/version, as my colleague who's working with the same code and the same files did not have this problem.

I tried many files and it ends in the same for all of them. I am aware that, for this mini example, I could make a workaround or use e.g. gdal (which works fine). But as these lines are just a part of a larger code and are supposed to work for new files immediately, I would like to have a real solution.

I am working with openSUSE 11.4, conda 4.3.23, Python 2.7.13, matplotlib 2.0.2 .

This could be a duplicate of [Value Error in reading tif image with pil in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44907780/value-error-in-reading-tif-image-with-pil-in-python). Due to the lack of specific information there, I open a new question. Sorry if that's the wrong way - my first post here...

Remark: I see that my tif file gets uploaded as png here. Is there a way to change that?

Comment: Do you have same version of libtiff library as your coleagues? Also, the image in the link is not a tiff but a png. Can you post the original tiff image which is giving you problems?

Comment: I didn't check their library versions in detail. And actually, I gave up on that problem and rewrote the code using `gdal`. As I wrote in the remark, I know about the wrong image format in the upload, but didn't know how to change that. I have not tried it yet, but there might be a solution/another workaround to the problem in the possible duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/a/50392977/8580469